# NHibernate 3.2 ignores entity-name

Tags: nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate 3.2 and have two tables mapped for same class, specifying the "entity-name" in mapping. The trouble is that when I use the method in ISession to indicate the entity name NHibernate insists deduct on their own behalf, ignoring my specification.

This is code from my unit tests:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public virtual Guid UID { get; set; }
    public virtual long Revisao { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
}

  <class name="Cliente">
    <id name="UID">
      <generator class="guid"/>
    </id>
    <version name="Revisao" />
    <property name="Nome" />
    <property name="DataNascimento" />
  </class>

  <class name="Cliente" entity-name="ClienteAudit" schema="audit">
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="UID" />
        <key-property name="Revisao" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="Nome" />
    <property name="DataNascimento" />
  </class>   

 var cliente = new Cliente {DataNascimento = DateTime.Parse("1988/07/09"), Nome = "Heber Senger"};
        using (var ss = sf.OpenSession())
        {
            ss.Save("Cliente", cliente);
            ss.Flush();
        }
```

NHibernate insists in save the entity as "ClienteAudit" (I verify in listener and table), and I explicity inform entity name as "Cliente".

I just try:
- Specify entity name in Cliente mapping;
- Omit name in method save, let NHibernate free to discover the name, implying in "ClienteAudit" again;
- Now I studying internal code of SessionImpl and so on.

If anyone can help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes were needed to all work:

1. Default type of version property is int and NOT long;
2. **And the most important**: the name specified in save method is the full name of class when entity-name don't was explicity indicated in HBM.

By the way, thanks!